# Issue when granting multiple roles on Discord upon a new member joining

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have an issue where my bot removes some of the roles he's supposed to grant after adding them to a user upon joining. My code is super simple and works with a single role just fine:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

    member.roles.add(['959889840353206342']);
    member.roles.add(['959890212870291456']);
    member.roles.add(['959996598413316127']);
    member.roles.add(['961700593221632070']);
})
```

However, upon a new member joining, this happens: [Discord Audit Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bf2G.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some `then` lines to that

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {

    member.roles.add('959889840353206342').then( () =>
        member.roles.add('959890212870291456')).then( () =>
        member.roles.add('959996598413316127')).then( () =>
        member.roles.add('961700593221632070'))
})
```

but the best option would be to do this

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {

    member.roles.add(['959889840353206342', '959890212870291456', '959996598413316127', '961700593221632070'])
})
```